# I keep getting error in meteor when I add autoform select2 bundle

Tags: meteor, jquery-select2, meteor-autoform

When I add select2 to my code. The field does not work as expected (with multiple selections) it gets larger but when you click in it nothing happens. There is also this error in the console

https://atmospherejs.com/aldeed/autoform-select2

```
Exception from Tracker afterFlush function:
debug.js:41 TypeError: $s.select2 is not a function
at Template.afSelect2.rendered (autoform-select2.js:126)
at runTemplateHooks (template-extension.js:375)
at templateExtensionMasterHook (template-extension.js:324)
at template.js:116
at Function.Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc (template.js:437)
at fireCallbacks (template.js:112)
at null.<anonymous> (template.js:205)
at view.js:104
at Object.Blaze._withCurrentView (view.js:523)
at view.js:103
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Are you on the latest version of the package?  Do you also have natestrauser:select2 installed?

Comment: @MarkLeiber is the natestrauser:select2 package also needed for autoform package? no i dont have that installed i will try now

Comment: it was required previously, but not for the latest version.

Comment: @MarkLeiber I added it and now it has taken away the error but the select2 form just is not pulling up any of the value. Also I am using version 2.0.2 of the autoform-select2

Comment: do you have a public repo that you can share?  We need to see more of your code to help.

Comment: Have same issue. Installing of `natestrauser:select2` helped but I'm not sure if it's good solution as newest `autoform-select2` uses select2 4.0+, and aldeed recommends to add 

```<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0-rc.1/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0-rc.1/js/select2.min.js"></script>```